# How to use a WEP key in iPod Touch?

Tags: wireless-networking, ipod-touch, wep

When I set-up my Netgear router I entered a WEP 128 bit passphrase.  Every device that I've connected to my network so far has asked for the *key*, but the iPod Touch (maybe in an effort to be user friendly) accepts only the *passphrase*.  I did make a note of the passphrase at the time, although what I noted down doesn't seem to be accepted.

Without resetting the key (because I now have several devices that would need to be reconfigured), is there any way I can get around this?  Either by just entering the WEP generated key into the iPod Touch or by reversing the key generation (I assume the former is more likely :-) ) ?

Comment: why WEP ? Why not WPA(2) ? That aside, you could login to the router and check what's the passphrase

Comment: Because I have a DS accessing the network.  The passphrase isn't displayed when you log into the router, only the key.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this after finding [this](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/travel-technology/742005-ipod-touch-wifi-wep.html) article.

It turns out that if you want to enter a WEP key into an iPod touch, you need to put a $ (dollar) sign in front of it and enter it into the password box!!

Comment: I never knew that!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the WEP key you wrote down is correct? Can you confirm by adding another device to the network?

As Sathya suggested, you can log in to see the WEP key that's in there now. If it is displayed as asterisks, you can simply view the HTML source of the configuration page to see the passphrase.

Personally, I'd reconfigure the security on the router to WPA2. Using WEP is like putting newspaper in your window frames during a tornado to keep the weather out.

Answer (score 0):

If one of your devices on the network is a Windows Vista/7 based machine, I'd download [WirelessKeyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html) and retrieve the passphrase

[image]